# "justifyContent: center" breaks correctly fitting layout with "height: 100%" (React Native / Flexbox)

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Here's my simplified code code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", width: 200}}>
    <View style={{borderWidth: 2, flex: 1, height: 100}}>
        <Text>flex: 1, height: 80</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{borderWidth: 2, width: 100, height: "100%", justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <Text>width: 100, height: 100%, justifyContent: center</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

These two boxes should line up height-wise. But when I add justifyContent: "center" to center the text inside them in the middle, the right box goes completely the wrong height. What's up?

[image: Normal]

[image: With justifyContent]

Comment: I think it's because of the parent div has this much height.

Comment: The code above is not the same as shown in the picture below... Could you please update everything correctly?

Comment: it will not happen if parent will have `height: 100`

Comment: The code is wrong, one has `height: 100` and the other has `height: '100%'`. There is no way they would be the same unless you provide `height: 100` to the parent element

Answer (score 0):

it's because justifyContent distributes all it's children along main-axis (column here) as per given space and as height: '100%', here it takes it's parent's height to distribute

There are two ways you can center the text : 
1 - change height: '100%' to a defined height as 100 and textAlign : 'center' to text

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200 }}>
    <View style={{ borderWidth: 2, flex: 1, height: 100, }}>
      <Text>flex: 1, height: 80</Text>
    </View>

    <View
      style={{
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,

       justifyContent : 'center'
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{textAlign : 'center'}}  >width: 100, height: 100, justifyContent: center</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

OR

2 - give a defined height to parent and textAlign : 'center' to text

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, height : 100 }}>
    <View style={{ borderWidth: 2, flex: 1, height: 100, }}>
      <Text>flex: 1, height: 80</Text>
    </View>

    <View
      style={{
        borderWidth: 2,
        width: 100,
        height: '100%',

       justifyContent : 'center'
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{textAlign : 'center'}}  >width: 100, height: 100%, justifyContent: center</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```

let me know if this works for you)